# Getting spurious value="{...}" when grabbing value of a textarea from the request in the Silex framework

Tags: php, silex

I am actually get all the rest of the values of the form correctly, except the value from the textarea, which contains

```
value="{...}"
```

Being the real value what comes inside the inverted commas. What can I do to avoid this behaviour?

Obviously I can "parse" that, but is it really advisable or is there a way to get the right value without further manipulation.

I am getting the value doing the following:

```
$req->get('message')
```

Being $req a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request object. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't what gets POSTed?

Comment: As @Maerlyn suggests, try to post a ```var_dump($_POST)```

Comment: When I do dump the $_POST, I get this, for that variable:

      'message' => string 'fafaf' (length=5)

And then i still get the value="" thing.

Comment: I already know what is happening, thanks for your help. It was being printed inside the value...